# Where is it appropriate to se the autogenerated columns' order in data grid?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I'm auto-generating a bunch of columns based on the definition of my model. I'd like to gain more control on the order in which they're displayed. Is it appropriate to do so from the fired event as shown below?

```
private void OnAutoGeneratedColumns(Object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) { ... }
```

Or is there a way to attribute the fields of the defining class so I can control in what order they're being shown? I'm binding the data grid to a list collection view in my view model, where I perform the filtration of which rows to display and which to conceal. Should I work with that instead?

```
public ListCollectionView AllThingiesView { ... }
```

Or is it, perhaps, an inappropriate approach to automatically generate the columns to begin with? I'm adding some of my own, that don't really have a corresponding property in the model.

## Edit

Based on the comments, I realize that the question might be clarified. I've got the partial answer - to use *DisplayOrder*. That answers the question of **how to do it**. The main issue is, however, **where** (or **when**) to do it. I've came up with several suggestions on where that property might be set, there might be others (better ones).

Also, it seems to be unclear what an attribute is. I wonder if it's possible to control/specify the index of a column using an attribute (and by that I mean an **attribute on a property**, not a property itself. For instance, the following pseudo-code shows what **could** be a possible approach.

```
public class GridableThing
{
  [Index(3)]
  public String FirstProperty{ get; set; })
  [Index(1)]
  public String SecondProperty{ get; set; })
  [Index(2)]
  public String ThirdProperty{ get; set; })
}
```

In the example above, if not set otherwise, the columns will appear in the order first-second-third. By using the property *DisplayIndex* of the grid, I could use **the attribute** of the properties to order them 3-1-2. Is this approach possible at all?

Comment: there is a DisplayIndex property that does exactly that

Comment: @Blam I might have been a bit unclear on the emphasis of the question. It's not **how to** but rather **where to** do it. I've learned that when it comes to WPF, a task can be achieved in many ways. Not all are appropriate, though... Should I go for the event handler, the view property or elsewhere entirely?

Comment: Or is there a way to attribute the fields of the defining class so I can control in what order they're being shown?

Comment: @Blam Well, there you go! Here I'm sitting thinking that you disregarded the intent of the question while in reality it about me missing your point. My only excuse is that I got confused by the shortness of the comment (as opposed to a reply - which you should use so I can accept it as an answer). At any rate, I stand corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my humble opinion the `AutoGeneratingColumns` event handler is not the right place for inserting the logic which manages the columns order. This event occurs when auto generation of all columns is completed, so when all columns are created you insert a logic for mixing them. Probably it is better to create them directly in the right order, without reordering them in a second moment.

Moreover, as you suggest, it would be great to use attributes for setting columns order (something like [Order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute.order(v=vs.110).aspx) property of DisplayAttribute). Doing this, in my opinion, means describing a class, *so my answer to your question is: put your logic in a* `CustomTypeDescriptor`. Ok, maybe you have to write more code and you can say that this is a long way to solve the problem. Maybe I am wrong, but I prefer this method for saying "this is the order of my columns (i.e. properties) of my class (or maybe my model)".

Of course in order to link your class to your CustomTypeDescriptor you need to use the `TypeDescriptionProvider` attribute:

```
[TypeDescriptionProvider(typeof(CustomTypeDescriptionProvider))]
public class Party : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    /* ... */
}
```

and to extend the `TypeDescriptionProvider` class:

```
public class CustomTypeDescriptionProvider : TypeDescriptionProvider
{
    private static TypeDescriptionProvider defaultTypeProvider =
                TypeDescriptor.GetProvider(typeof(Party));

    public CustomTypeDescriptionProvider()
        : base(defaultTypeProvider)
    {
    }

    public override ICustomTypeDescriptor GetTypeDescriptor(Type objectType, object instance)
    {
        ICustomTypeDescriptor defaultDescriptor =
                            base.GetTypeDescriptor(objectType, instance);

        return new CustomTypeDescriptor(defaultDescriptor, instance);
    }

    public ICustomTypeDescriptor GetBaseTypeDescriptor(Type objectType, object instance)
    {
        return base.GetTypeDescriptor(objectType, instance);
    }
}
```

The last step is to create your `CustomTypeDescriptor`:

```
class CustomTypeDescriptor : System.ComponentModel.CustomTypeDescriptor
{
    private List<PropertyDescriptor> propertyDescriptors = new List<PropertyDescriptor>();
    private PropertyDescriptorCollection propertyDescriptorCollection;

    public CustomTypeDescriptor(ICustomTypeDescriptor parent, object instance)
        : base(parent)
    {
        CustomTypeDescriptionProvider customTypeDescriptionProvider = new WpfApplication1.CustomTypeDescriptionProvider();
        ICustomTypeDescriptor typeDescriptor = customTypeDescriptionProvider.GetBaseTypeDescriptor(typeof(Party), null);
        PropertyDescriptorCollection tempPropertyDescriptorCollection = typeDescriptor.GetProperties();
        propertyDescriptors.Add(tempPropertyDescriptorCollection[2]);
        propertyDescriptors.Add(tempPropertyDescriptorCollection[1]);
        propertyDescriptors.Add(tempPropertyDescriptorCollection[0]);
        /* put here your ordering logic */

        propertyDescriptorCollection = new PropertyDescriptorCollection(propertyDescriptors.ToArray());
    }

    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties()
    {
        return propertyDescriptorCollection;
    }

    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        return propertyDescriptorCollection;
    }
}
```

Here I'm using the default `TypeDescriptor` to retrive the PropertyDescriptors of `Party` object. Then I sort them in the way I prefer (eventually I can read attributes for determining the right order).

It would be great to hear some feedbacks to my idea.

Comment: I was hoping there was a default attribute for the ordering in .NET that I haven't found. Worst case scenario - as you suggest - I might implement it myself. What is the actual **default** mechanism of obtaining the list of public properties, anyway? I've never thought about that until now but when iterating over the public properties, the framework must somehow order it (not that it bears any significance, of course, but still)... I'm guessing that's the **default** order for automatic binding. At any rate: +1 for extensive code base.

Comment: Unfortunately, as far as I know, a default attribute does not exist for WPF. I _believe_ that the framework orders properties in the same order they are declared.